# How to fix 'Method is undefined for type' error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to implement a method which replaces one of the elements in a 2D array

```
public class GameBoard {

    public static final char EMPTY = '.';
    public static final char PLAYER1 = 'X';
    public static final char PLAYER2 = 'O';

    public static final int ROWS = 6;
    public static final int COLUMNS = 7;
    private char[][] board;
    public char[][] getBoard(){
         return board;
    }
    public char[][] get_move( int move, char player) {
         char[][] x = getBoard();
         if (player == PLAYER1 || player == PLAYER2) {
             for (int row = 0; row<ROWS; row++) {
                 if (x[row][move] == EMPTY) {
                         x[row][move] = player;
                         return x;
                 }
             }
         }
         else {
             return board;
         }
         return getBoard();

   }

  public static GameBoard setBoardForTest(int[] moves, GameBoard board){
      char player = PLAYER1;
      for(int move: moves){


          board.getMove(move, player);

          if(player == PLAYER1){
              player = PLAYER2;
          }
          else{
              player = PLAYER1;
          }
      }
      return board; 
 }
```

However I keep getting an error when I call board.getMove(player,move) in the setBoardForTest() method that the method getMove(int, char) is undefined for the type GameBoard

Comment: and where is the method `getMove` - I also can **not** find it - there is only a `get_move`, but, despite similar, it is different

Comment: get_move , getMove. Two different names ?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the method `get_move`, not `getMove`. Just rename it and you should be OK.